# Calling standard functions from assembly in windows

Tags: windows, assembly

I'm toying around with assembly and the actualy bytes that it produces after translation (on x86 anyway), and I found myself asking this:

In Linux, when you want to call say printf, you would place the arguments and the call code on the stack and then call int 0x80. That is very elegant, and will always translate into the same bytes.

But on Windows, I tried compiling a small program, like so

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("abcdefgh");
    return 0;
}
```

and then disassembling it. Which, produces something like "call _printf", where _printf stands for something like "jmp    *0x406124" and two nops (even with static linking!).

I assume the address in the jump is dynamically loaded address for the library function of printf, so this could potentially be different during each load? Or am I completely wrong here? Then, how does the dynamic loader know what function the program wants to call, just from the instruction code (which will probably be a near call with such short program)? Does the dynamic linker change the instruction codes themselves?

This all seems like an awful lot of trouble for simple system calls, but I know that Windows will work with int 0x80 codes too, except that function codes change quite often (or so I'm told). What would be the simpliest way to call printf (or any other syscall) directly in instructions on Windows then?

Comment: No, if you want `printf` on linux you don't do `int 0x80` because that is a syscall and `printf` is a library function. Also syscalls don't take arguments on the stack. In fact it's the same on linux, you get a `call printf` which will go to an indirect jump through a pointer filled in by the dynamic linker.

Comment: Yep, on Linux the pointers in the Procedure Linking Table (I think that's the right name) start out pointing to a routine that looks up the actual symbol address in the library.  The first call goes first through the symbol lookup function, which updates the jump table, then jumps to the actual function in the library.  So dynamic linking is done lazily.  Try single-stepping in asm for the first call vs. the second call.  What you describe seeing on Windows **looks the same as Linux**.

Comment: Google for "Import Address Table" (IAT). This was my first result: http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Understanding_imports.html